# How do you say "under an angel's wing" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, motto

How do you say "under an angel's wing" in Latin? Should it be *sub ala angelus* or *sub ala angeli*? A friend of mine has a tattoo (using the 1st option), and she's afraid it's not correct.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Your nice question has earned you enough reputation that you can now vote up any questions and answers you like. Just click the little arrow up next to a post. That's the best way to reward people here. If you think your question has been fully settled, you can choose one answer as an accepted answer by clicking the little green check mark under the voting gadget.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the latter option. *Angelus* would be nominative, i.e. the subject of the sentence, whereas *angeli* here would denote possession. If she got the former translation, it reads "an angel under a wing," so it's nothing too embarrassing.

Comment: You beat me to it by 8 seconds!

Comment: Probably too late if your friend is already worried, but in general I'd recommend against telling people their tattoos are incorrect when it's too late to do anything about it!

Comment: @dbmag9 And I'd recommend never getting a tattoo written in a language you aren't fluent in, or failing that, consult someone you *really* trust (i.e. not strangers on the internet) who is fluent.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman You don't have to convince me! Very much agreed; the number of tattoo requests here always worry me, but each to their own.

Comment: She just had her tattoo removed, so everything will be fine

Answer (score 10):

The first phrasing you quote has the nominative case *angelus* of the Latin word for an angel.
Thus it means roughly:

> *Sub ala angelus.*
> [There is] an angel under [a/the] wing.

Latin often leaves out "is" and doesn't need "there" or an article.
The phrase makes sense, but the wing belongs to someone other than the angel.

The second one uses the genitive case *angeli*.
This gets the meaning correct:

> *Sub ala angeli.*
> Under the wing of an angel.